# How to change TFS 2010 Beta 2 Connection String for Config DB

Tags: tfs

I've just installed Team Foundation Server 2010 Beta 2. Don't know how but the Connection String for the Data Backend (Configuration Database) is defined using "IntegratedSecurity" which is a bad thing. I have no (more) idea(s) about how to change that Connection String. Anyone smarter than me? ;-)

Comment: Why is integrated security a bad thing?

Comment: Good Question! My understanding of integrated security is that all db access is done with the tfs service user (tfsservice). In that case, integrated is great. What drives me crazy is the problem that i get "access to db denied" errors all the time. As soon as i log on as tfsservice (i know, a no-go. Just for test ;-), tfs works great. That made me think that impersonation might play a role in the game but meanwhile, i guess that's not true. However, strange problem and i'm a little bit lost at the moment.

Answer (score 11):

I think you need to edit the web.config file (by default in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web Services), find the appsettings node, and modify the applicationDatabase value.